# LaTeX and evince problem. Evince does not attach to edges of the screen

Tags: compiling, pdf, latex, evince

I just use ST3 for LaTeX. LaTeXTools requires one of this pdf-viewers: evince, okular, zathura. I like evince because it is very simple and fast pdf-viewer. But have an issue: when I compile my pdf file and then evince open it, it just does not attach to left or right edges of the screen. I  still can attach it to top or bottom edges, but it is do not convenient to use.

Even I close the file and open singly from ST3, issue still is. If I open an another file which was not build with LaTeXTools, there is not the issue.

Comment: Are you using the standard Ubuntu desktop (Gnome Shell?). What do you mean with "attach to top or bottom edges"? Standard Ubuntu can tile to the left or the right of the screen (touching bottom and top edges) but not top and bottom (touching left and right edge), Clarify your question more specifically.

Comment: No, I use Cinnamon. Sorry, I might top and bottom sides of screen, but not edges

Comment: What is ST3 and LaTeXTools? How did you installed them? What was wrong with TexStudio, TexMaker running on top of TeXLive distribution from the repository?

Comment: ST3 is Sublime Text 3, LaTeXTools is package for ST3 needed to compile TeX files. You can search any manual how to install it. I used TeXStudio, and it has terrible and uncomfortable interface, it also has a little bit of themes. TeXMaker is worse than TeXStudio by my oppinion. If you try switch white Linux interface theme on dark your eyes will die using TeXStudio. I had an another reason cause I change TeXStudio on ST3 + LaTeXTools, but I do not remember what the reaseon is